# Finding different versions of a searched string in python3

Tags: python, search

what I want, is to find a string string even if I use the wrong notation or the string is stored in wrong notation.
Especially, I read a text file (or later a database) containing song titles and artist names, all in latin.
So, if I'm looking for

- Fernandez I'd like to also find Fernandes, or
- Korazon  ...................... corazón (or visa versa) or
- La Banda X .................... (only:) Banda X
- ...

More or less like a google search.
Is there some special module/software? 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+similarity+words) can help you. After ordering and calculating the similarity between each pair of values, you can use a name dictionary to replace the values with a high degree of similarity. So for example, knowing that `Korazon` and `corazón` have a high degree of similarity, they should be selected for replacement.

Comment: I think you have to take a look at `regex` then you'll have to build a huge collection of them to get what you want.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: See [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Many, many thanks!<br/>
It's good hints and a lot of stuff to work through:-)<br/>

Comment: It's a very good idea! It says then invalid syntax and "GET" is highlighted. But why?